# How to make a new Path object from parts of a current path with pathlib?

Tags: python, pathlib

I would like to change a part of a Path object with `pathlib`.

For example if you have a Path object:

```
import pathlib
path = pathlib.Path("/home/user/to/some/floder/toto.out")
```

How can I change the file name ? And get a new path with for example `"/home/user/to/some/folder/other_file.dat"` ?

Or more generally, one can I change one or several elements of that path ?

I can get the `parts` of the path:

```
In [1]: path.parts
Out[1]: ('/', 'home', 'user', 'to', 'some', 'floder', 'toto.out')
```

Thus, a workaround is to join the needed parts, make a new string and then a new path, but I wonder if there is a more convenient tool to do that.

**EDIT**

To be more precise, does it exist an equivalent to `path.name` that return the complementary part of the path : `str(path).replace(path.name, "")`.

Comment: What does "complementary" mean here? Do you mean the parent, as in  `path.parent`? In that case, you could just do `other_path = path.parent / 'other_file.dat'`

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for to change the file name. Is there also a way to change a given part ? For example `some` in `other` in my path ?

Comment: Yes. Split the path, change the element you want, and join the path again: `path_parts = path.parts; path_parts[4] = 'other'; path=Path(*path_parts)`

Comment: Thanks, it works if you convert `parts` to list (tuple being immutable) `path_parts = list(path.parts)`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In order to sum up the comments, the statements are the following:

1. In order to change the file name

```py
In [1]: import pathlib

In [2]: path = pathlib.Path("/home/user/to/some/folder/toto.out")

In [3]: path.parent / "other_file.dat"
Out[3]: PosixPath('/home/user/to/some/folder/other_file.dat')
```

2. In order to change one part in the path

```py
In [4]: parts = list(path.parts)

In [5]: parts[4] = "other"

In [6]: pathlib.Path(*parts)
Out[6]: PosixPath('/home/user/to/other/folder/toto.out')
```

Comment: Is there a method chaining way to change path?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `str.format` to have variable filenames

**Ex:**

```
import pathlib
filename = "other_file.dat"    #Variable. 
path = pathlib.Path("/home/user/to/some/floder/{0}".format(filename))
```

Comment: Yes, I can do something like `str(path).replace(path.name,"")`. But I wonder if there is an analog at `path.name` that return the complementary part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`PurePath.with_name()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_name), for example:

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path("/tmp/some.txt").with_name("other.txt")
PosixPath('/tmp/other.txt')
```

There also is `with_suffix()` and `with_stem()` to cover other, similar needs.